# Mapreduce for word count on specific column in txt file

Tags: python, mapreduce, word-count

I have mapper and reducer code to find the most frequent word in a text file. I want to output the most common word/words in my text file in a specific column. The name of the column in the txt file is 'genres'. The column has multiple strings separated by commas. Here is a sample of my txt file :

```
tconst  averageRating   numVotes    titleType   primaryTitle    startYear   genres
tt0002020   5.2 85  short   Queen Elizabeth 1912    Biography,Drama,History
tt0002026   4   7   movie   Anny - Story of a Prostitute    1912    Drama,Romance
tt0002029   6.1 33  short   Poor Jenny  1912    Short
tt0002031   4.6 8   movie   As You Like It  1912    \N
tt0002033   5.6 26  short   Asesinato y entierro de Don JosŽ Canalejas  1912    Short
tt0002034   4.9 17  short   At Coney Island 1912    Comedy,Short
tt0002041   3.9 14  short   The Baby and the Stork  1912    Crime,Drama,Short
tt0002045   4.2 71  short   The Ball Player and the Bandit  1912    Drama,Romance,Short

    //Mapper code   
    import sys

        def read_input(file):
            for line in file:
                # split the line into words
                yield line.split()

        def main(separator='\t'):
            # input comes from STDIN (standard input)
            data = read_input(sys.stdin)
            for words in data:
                # write the results to STDOUT (standard output);
                # what we output here will be the input for the
                # Reduce step, i.e. the input for reducer.py
                #
                # tab-delimited; the trivial word count is 1
                for word in words:
                    print '%s%s%d' % (word, separator, 1)

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            main()



 //Reducer
    from itertools import groupby
    from operator import itemgetter
    import sys

    current_word = None
    current_count = 0
    word = None
    max_count = 0
    max_word = None

    for line in sys.stdin:
        # remove leading and trailing whitespace
        line = line.strip()

        # parse the input we got from mapper.py
        word, count = line.split('\t', 1)

        # convert count (currently a string) to int
        try:
            count = int(count)
        except ValueError:
            # count was not a number, so silently
            # ignore/discard this line
            continue

        # this IF-switch only works because Hadoop sorts map output
        # by key (here: word) before it is passed to the reducer
        if current_word == word:
            current_count += count
        else:
            # check if new word greater
            if current_count > max_count:
                max_count= current_count 
                max_word = current_word        
            current_count = count
            current_word = word

    # do not forget to check last word if needed!
    if current_count > max_count:
        max_count= current_count 
        max_word = current_word

    print '%s\t%s' % (max_word, max_count)
```

Can you guide me on how I can alter this code to print most frequent words in the 'genres' column. I also would like to output the word count for all the words in the Please let me know if I need to provide anything else.

Comment: Why does the input come from stdin? I’m confused, maybe I’m missing something?

Comment: @AMC I just followed the tutorial [link](https://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/). I think it is being used to store the whole txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a multiple of the index of the line variable. Use the index whichever specific column you want to find the most frequent word of.